# how to let time as row names in data frame

Tags: r

I used read.table read a txt  file into dataframe ,I want to the time to be
the raw names and the time property not changed

```
ul <- read.table("d:/work/R/202b.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t", row.names=1)
```

and ul like this

```
           DIS        F       TOTAL           X  y
13:20:13   493.1259   0.36044 22422.43        0 NA
13:20:15   493.7804   0.36091 22422.68        0 NA
    .
14:20:13   404.17580  0.29542  22869.23       0 NA
14:20:15   402.21930  0.29399  22869.50       0 NA    .
```

I want to get the ul[14:20:13, 3]
and it didn't get the  22869 it get this

```
[1] 22425.95 22425.62
Warning message:
In 14:20:13 : numerical expression has 7 elements: only the first used
```

How do I make the time series be the row names and like R know it

Comment: Try `ul["14:20:13", 3]`

Comment: row names in R are character (hence the "name' part). Furthermore, there's no "time" object in base R (there are date/time objects but that's not what you are using here). Other packages introduce "time"-like objects but they can't be used as row names. FWIW _most_ (not all) modern R practices avoid the use of row names, preferring the use of column indexing